# Where the AppDelegate get set as a delegate for the application?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift5, xcode12

Environment, Swift 5.3 and Xcode 12

Normally we do `someObject.delegate = self` to set the current class as the delegate for some class instance. However, inside `AppDelegate` there is no such assignment to make it a delegate of the application.

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {}

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {}
}
```

So where the application's `delegate` property get set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@UIApplicationMain` attribute means that this class **is the application delegate**, https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID589.

It's the same as calling the `UIApplicationMain(:,:,:,:)`. If the attribute is NOT used, supply a `main.swift` file with code at the top level that calls `UIApplicationMain(:,:,:,:)` (also applicable to `NSApplication`).

Adding `@main` seems to have the same effect as `@UIApplicationMain`. Replace `@main` with `@UIApplicationMain` and the app works just fine, tested.